# Hide pseudo after element when hovering this element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My menu is placed vertically on the left side of the page and between the `<li>` I have an `:after` that is a separator. What I want to have is to hide the after element when I hover the element itself (if it's the first element) or the above and the bottom one when it's the middle one and if it's the last child just the `:after` element of the previous `<li>`. This may sound confusing but here is my code:

```css
.menu {
  float: left;
  color: white;
}
.menu > ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu > ul > li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 60% 5px;
  background-color: #048990;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.menu > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
}
.menu > ul > li:hover .menu > ul > li::after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu > ul > li:active {
  background-color: #444;
}
.menu >ul >li:after {
  content: "";
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 7%;
  height: 1px;
  width: 86%;
}
.menu > ul > li:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xaf3bn2/2/)

Now all I want to do is something like this:

```
.menu > ul > li:hover + .menu > ul > li::after
{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

But it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `.menu > ul > li:hover::after`

Comment: @Harry Thanks that was fast and it worked can you help me with the middle ones as well? and if possible post it as answer so I can mark it. Thanks

Comment: You cannot use pure CSS selectors to hide the `::after` of the previous element because CSS selectors can only select child, descendants, siblings that follow the current element (not the ones before it). Anyways, I will post a different method as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below selector would not work because the full selector should not be repeated when using `+` adjacent sibling combinator. This would try to select the `li::after` that is under `.menu > ul` which is in-turn the adjacent sibling of the `li` that is being hovered on.

```css
.menu > ul > li:hover + .menu > ul > li::after {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

It should instead be written as `.menu > ul > li:hover::after` if you want to select the `::after` of the `li` that is being hovered on (or) as `.menu > ul > li:hover + li::after` if you want to select the `::after` element of the `li` that is the adjacent sibling of the `li` which is being hovered on.

---

The other problem with the approach that you are using currently is that CSS selectors can be used only to select the children, descendants or the siblings that appear after the current element in DOM. They cannot be used to target the previous siblings and so if the `::after` of  each element is used to create the separator then the separator on top can never be hidden.

Instead, we can use the `::before` elements (on all but the `first-child`) to create the separator. In this scenario we can use CSS selectors to hide both the the current element's `::before` and the next element's `::before` on hover.

```css
.menu {
  float: left;
  color: white;
}
.menu > ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu > ul > li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 60% 5px;
  background-color: #048990;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.menu > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
}
.menu > ul > li:hover + li::before,
.menu > ul > li:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu > ul > li:active {
  background-color: #444;
}
.menu >ul >li:not(:first-child)::before {
  content: "";
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 7%;
  height: 1px;
  width: 86%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```